# Unable to figure out the type of SSD I have

Tags: ssd, sata, pci-express, nvme, msata

SSD:
[image: SSD]

Can anyone please help me find out whether this SSD is SATA M.2 or NVMe?
Thanks

Comment: @squillman Please post this as an answer.

Comment: It says "PCI Express" on the label by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this flyer from Kingston](https://media.kingston.com/pdfs/emmc/MKF-815_design-in_SSD_lr.pdf), being a U-SNS8154P3/512GJ it's NVMe

Here is the relative bit from the flyer in the case the link dies at some point.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll get an NVMe enclosure